# How to do form validation for a select box?

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

I am trying to provide an error message when users do not pick a value on the select box. The VMware Clarity documentation is pretty clear when we are dealing with `<input type="text">` elements ([click here](https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/input-fields)), which says:

> You can use validation styling for input fields by wrapping the input
>   tag in a container with the .tooltip class along with the
>   .tooltip-validation class. Use the .invalid class on the
>   .tooltip-validation container to toggle the validation styling. Place
>   the .tooltip-content after the input tag.

There is no documentation explaining how we should do validation with select boxes ([click here](https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/select-boxes)).

So, I tried the following:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="technology">Technology</label>
    <div class="select tooltip tooltip-validation tooltip-sm invalid">
        <select formControlName="technology">
            <option value=""
                disabled>- Select an API Technology -</option>
            <option *ngFor="let technology of technologies"
                [value]="technology">{{technology}}</option>
        </select>
        <span class="tooltip-content">
            Technology is required.
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the result that I am getting:

[image]

Notice that the tooltip icon is there, but when the user clicks, it does not show the desired content "Technology is required"

**My question is: What is the best practice to do validation with select boxes?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO, you **do not** need validation of any kind with select boxes. The reason being, for a select box you do specify what can be the possible selections and the user *must* select one of them.

Keep it simple: you do not need to show the extra option `<option value="" disabled>- Select an API Technology -</option>`. Just show the available `technologies`.

If you really want, you can show a static warning. Check this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/gCgmzU.

Comment: Changing business requirements is not always possible. Answer such as this is not in the spirit of Stack Overflow, because anyone directed here via Google would only learn your opinion on UX, not the solution to the problem.

Comment: Well, this is not an opinion. I used *IMO* as a humble way to put my thoughts. Every design or algorithm has a philosophy, and I wanted to highlight it. Sometimes you just cannot generalize thing, and need to put things in perspective. 
I am a regular user of stack overflow and I saw many such answers, including accepted answers, presented in the similar fashion. Any, IMO, it does not violate the spirit of Stack Overflow. Every problem is different, and not every problem has a solution in black and white.

Comment: @SoumyaKanti Thanks for your help. My form is quite complex, some select boxes need to have a value. Your suggestion is good, and I am following that. But, I posted this question here in hope that there would be some Clarity documentation not only for text area validation but also for the select box.

Comment: @Max I have posted one more answer, which may fit to your requirement. I am still in favor of the first answer though.

Comment: @SoumyaKanti I prefer your first answer too.

Answer (score 1):

I worked out a solution that can work for you:

**app.component.html:**

```
<clr-main-container>
  <div class="content-container">
    <div class="content-area">
      <form class="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [hidden]="submitted">
        <section class="form-block">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="technology">API Technology</label>
            <div class="select">
              <select class="form-control" name="technology" (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
                <option value="" disabled>- Select an API Technology -</option>
                <option *ngFor="let technology of technologies" [value]="technology">{{technology}}</option>
              </select>
              <span class="tooltip-content" *ngIf="hide">
                  Technology is required.
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </form>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</clr-main-container>
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
export class AppComponent {
  public hide: boolean = true;
  public technologies = ["RPC", "SOAP", "REST"];

  onChange(technology) {
    console.log(technology);
    this.hide = false;
  }
}
```

Here is the Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/G5tuUCh1gc4xPTBiJWxe.